# React Native 0.64 FBReactNativeSpec SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) PhaseScriptExecution

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am unable to run a brand new React Native project in an iOS simulator.

---

Here's my environment:

- OS: macOS Big Sir 11.2.3
- NodeJS: 15.14.0
- react-native: 0.64.0
- react-native-cli: 2.0.1

---

Here's what I am doing:

- Create a new react native project using `react-native init FooBar`.
- Run the project in iOS using `react-native run-ios`

---

After that I get the following error:

[image: FBReactNativeSpec Error]

```
/Volumes/Projects/FooBar/node_modules/react-native-codegen/lib/cli/combine/combine-js-to-schema-cli.js:25
  );
  ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:974:3
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the problem lies with a bug with Facebook's React Native version 0.64.

The culprit is: `node_modules/react-native/scripts/find-node.sh`.

The temporary workaround until Facebook fixes it is to remove the contents of the file without deleting the file. I've automated this with the following script:

```
echo '' > node_modules/react-native/scripts/find-node.sh # Fix for React Native 0.64.0 (until Facebook fixes it)
```